# Can I temporarily disable an handler?

Tags: jquery, handler

I have a link with an image, where it is attached a click and a draggable handler.

I'd like to disable the click handler if I move the link (e.g. if I drag it).

Than, re-active it, so if after I just click, I get it.

How can I do? .unbind will remove the whole handler, I think...

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? Unbinding is not necessary, you can conditionally call 'preventDefault' or return false. But there's no real way of telling without viewing the code

Comment: preventDefault doesn't stop the current function from happening, it only stops the event from bubbling up. See api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault Return false would work though :-) See my answer

Comment: this is the scenario : http://jsfiddle.net/Wrevr/2/ (sorry, can't add jquery UI on fiddle)

Comment: Doh! ofcourse, only the *default* event would be cancelled out, not other actions added by scripts. Thanks for pointing that out ;)

Comment: Judging the fiddle, you could bind on the 'stop' part, and unbind on the 'start' part, but I'm not sure this is best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean, you dont want anchor click event to interfere during dragging, then you can capture all click events on the link/anchor tag and hook it up with the stop event on draggable, something like:

```
var cancelFollow = false; 
$(function(){ 

  $("anchorElement").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (cancelFollow)
    {
      cancelFollow = false;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });

  $("imageElement").draggable({
    .... 
    start: function(e, ui){},

    stop: function(e, ui){     
      cancelFollow = true;

    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// bind it
$('#id').on('click', click_handler);

// unbind it
$('#id').off('click', click_handler);

// bind it again
$('#id').on('click', click_handler);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`.unbind('click')` if you used `.bind()`

or:

`.off('click')` if you used `.on()`

Otherwise you can add an exception:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
   if ( ... ) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

---

EDIT:

Using jQuery-UI it works fine without any stop handler on a link, if you can be interested in this solution I did a **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4XXL/)**

Comment: preventDefault does not stop the current function from happening, it only stops the event from bubbling up. See http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: I also added a solution with jQuery-ui draggable if you can be interested on it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of unbinding and then rebinding the handler, I think it would be more readable to implement a global variable (boolean) that functions as a killswitch.

I see no code snippet in your question so I'll just post a random example:

```
var doNotExecute = false;

$(".myClassItem").click(function() {

    if(doNotExecute) return false;;

    //Now do your normal processing.

});
```

Now you have the option to set `doNotExecute` to `true` whenever you want to stop the event from really happening. Just remember to set it back to `false` afterwards :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create your handler in the global scope ..
Click may not be triggered on drag action ...
Considering this, to me the best way would be to use event delegation to prevent from unbinding event, using

```
$('#container').on('click', 'ATagClass', handler(e){/* ... */});
```

Inside the handler you will have to check whether the e.target is your tag by checking its class or whatever property ... make sure that #container will always be ancestor of your a tags.